# JavaScript Card Flip: Card Back Data is Outside of the Card

Tags: javascript, css, api

I am trying to have a card flip between front and back, with different data displayed on each. However my code as it stands now shows both the front and back side by side, and when I click on the card it flips it over but just have everything reversed. So I need to move the back of the card data into the card and have it show once flipped.

My HTML just has the container for the card.

```
<h1>POKEDEX</h1>
<div id="poke_container" class="poke_container"></div>
```

Here is my JavaScript function that gets data from the API, along with the InnerHTML for both the front and back of the card.

```
function createPokemonCard(pokemon) {
    const pokemonEl = document.createElement('div');
    const pokemonElBack = document.createElement('div');
    pokemonEl.classList.add('pokemon');
    const poke_types = pokemon.types.map(el => el.type.name);
    const type = pokemon.types[0].type.name;
    //const stats = pokemon.stats[0].stat.name;
    const ability = pokemon.abilities[0].ability.name;
    const name = pokemon.name[0].toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
    const card_color = colors[type];

    pokemonEl.style.backgroundColor = card_color;

    //Card Front data and HTML
    const pokeInnerHTML = `
    <div class="front">
    <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://pokeres.bastionbot.org/images/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" />
    </div>
    <div class ="info">
      <span class="number">#${pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0')}</span>
      <a href="https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/${name}_(Pok%C3%A9mon)" class="name"><h3>${name}</h3></a>
      <small class="type"><span>${type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)}</span></small>
    </div>
    </div>
    `;

    pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML;

    poke_container.appendChild(pokemonEl);

// Back of the card data
  const pokeCardBack = `
    <div class="flipped">
      <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" />
      </div>
      <div class ="info">
        <span class="number">#${pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0')}</span>
        <h3 class="name">${name}</h3>
        <small class="type"><span>${ability}</span></small>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;

    pokemonElBack.innerHTML = pokeCardBack;

    poke_container.appendChild(pokemonElBack);

    //Flip card from front to back function
    const back = document.querySelectorAll('.pokemon');

    function flipCard() {
      this.classList.toggle('flipped');
    }
    back.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));

}});
```

Here is my CSS. Most is just for the card design, but flipped is supposed to be for the back of the card. Right now it just flips the card but only shows a mirror version of the front instead of the data on the back.

```
.poke_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.pokemon {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .3s;
      &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

.pokemon .img-container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pokemon .img-container img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.pokemon .info {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.pokemon .number {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.pokemon .name {
  margin: 15px 0 7px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}


.pokemon .type {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.pokemon.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

I hope the information above is clear. I am really trying to switch between the const pokeInnerHTML to const pokeCardBack. I am not sure why my card back data is outside of my card right now. It should be tied to the flipped div.

Comment: have a look at css property backface-visibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility

Comment: I don't think that's it, I've added it to my divs but it's not having an effect. The back of the card is visible but it is just side by side with the front for some reason. I am not sure if it is a JavaScript function or CSS problem or both.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ehn6oma9/ (I changed a bunch of stuff, the key is to set the back of the card to `position: absolute` so it appears in the same position as the front)

Comment: it depends on what you whant to achiev. If you want a real 3D flipping card, have a look at my answer. If you just want to show either front or back from your card, make on back display: none; and on flip change back visibility to display: none anf front to display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the `backface-visibility` setting it to hidden should do the trick.

Have a look here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)

You want a fliping card, right? Then create a 3D perspective and make the backface invisible. See Demo with your code below or [this](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/card-flip) tutorial.

Demo (click the flip button to flip the card):

```js
$("#flip").click(function(){$(".pokemon").toggleClass("flipped")});
```

```css
.card{
  width: 400px;
  height: 170px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.pokemon {
  transform-origin: center right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pokemon .front{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.pokemon .flipped{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.pokemon .img-container img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.pokemon .info {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.pokemon .number {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.pokemon .name {
  margin: 15px 0 7px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}


.pokemon .type {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.pokemon.flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="pokemon">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://pokeres.bastionbot.org/images/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="number">#${pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0')}</span>
        <a href="https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/${name}_(Pok%C3%A9mon)" class="name">
          <h3>${name}</h3>
        </a>
        <small class="type"><span>${type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)}</span></small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipped">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="number">#${pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0')}</span>
        <h3 class="name">${name}</h3>
        <small class="type"><span>${ability}</span></small>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<button id="flip">
flip!
</button>
```